# Где выполнять команду git clone?

Tags: git, shell

Может мне кто-нибудь объяснить как воспользоваться вот этим?

```
git clone git://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client.git
cd socket.io-java-client
ant jar
mv jar/socketio.jar /path/to/your/libs/project
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это команды в синтаксисе [unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) ([shell](/questions/tagged/shell), [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)) - интерпретатора командной строки в unix-совместимых ОС.

Поскольку у вас Windows, то есть как минимум два способа этим воспользоваться.

1. Установить unix-совместимую консоль, например git bash или cygwin.
2. Установить unix-совместимую ОС. ))

Конкретнее о командах, если вы хотите разобраться в происходящем:

- `cd`, `mv` - стандартные команды shell "перейти в папку" и "переместить/переименовать файлы". Точка входа - множество, [например вот тут.](http://citforum.ru/programming/shell/index.shtml)
- `git` - распределенная система контроля версий Git, [git](/questions/tagged/git), с помощью которой вы получаете файлы на свой ПК. Точка входа: [Pro Git (на русском)](http://www.git-scm.com/book/ru/v1)
- `ant` - Apache Ant, [ant](/questions/tagged/ant) - система сборки для JVM-платформы. Точки входа: [русский](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant), [english](http://ant.apache.org/).

Comment: Спасибо, всё очень даже понятно разъяснили

Comment: @Сергей добро пожаловать в юниксовый мир )))

Comment: Вообще я не вижу тут команд, специфичных именно для Unix'овой оболочки. При наличии в виндовом комнадном интерпретаторе доступным в `PATH` утилитам `git` и `ant` это должно и в обычном `.bat`-файле отработать. Хотя чтобы поставить `git` на Windows без юниксовой оболочки нынче надо постараться :)

Comment: @D-side отлично, я не знал, что так можно.

Answer (score 2):

Это команды для командной строки.

1. Скопировать проект из репозитория гитхаба на локальную машину
2. перейти в папку проекта
3. собрать проект
4. переместить .jar файл в другую папку

Воспользоватся - ввести в командную строку.

Comment: Но у меня постоянно CMD выбивает следующее -- "git" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: @Сергей так его надо установить. Как вероятней всего и ant

Comment: @Сергей а как Вы хотите воспользоваться git, если он не установлен у   Вас ? Установите его.

Comment: Простите, а где его взять? :D

Comment: @Сергей, попробуйте скачат .zip архив из репозитория гитхаба, если не хотите ставить гит.

Comment: @Сергей, ничего личного - но попробуйте загуглить "git download"

Comment: Ок. Спасибо за наводку. А вот это `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/Gottox/socket.io-java-client ` что такое?

Comment: И вот это --> `cd $PATH_TO_SOCKETIO_JAVA
ant jar
ls jar/socketio.jar` Простите за такую наглость)

Comment: @Сергей, по-моему, команда VCS Mercurial на клонирования репозитория из битбакета.

Comment: Просто узнать хочу..не более

Comment: @Сергей на будущие - не стоит задаввть столько вопросов в коменты, особенно если не по теме. Есть конкретный вопрос - на него участники дают конкретный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, пошёл я дальше мучатся :D Вопрос закрыт

Comment: @Сергей cd - команда перехода по директориям.

Comment: Но ведь это всё к этой теме относится, оффтопа я не заметил за собой

Comment: @Сергей, не совсем так. Вы задали много вопрос по разным командам.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что на каждый свой НОВЫЙ вопрос я должен создавать по 10 - 20 тем? Это приемлемо?

Comment: @Сергей я хочу сказать, что такие вопросы вообще не нужно задавать! Вопрос не конкретный это раз. Вопрос легко гуглится это два.